# How to pass pdflatex option "-synctex=1" to texi2dvi?

Tags: pdftex, forward-inverse-search, texi2dvi

How can I pass the option `-synctex=1` (for synctex support) of `pdflatex` to `texi2dvi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create an environment variable called PDFLATEX, which includes the argument(s) you want to pass. Thus, on my machine the following worked.

```
setenv PDFLATEX "pdflatex -synctex=1"
texi2dvi -p mydocument.tex
```

Comment: Or `PDFLATEX="pdflatex -synctex=1" texi2dvi -p file` in Bash. Probably it's better to add also the Bash equivalent of exporting an environment variable: there's few of us using tcsh, nowadays. :)